# Configure OkHttpClient instance used by other libraries

Tags: android, ssl, okhttp

I am using a library to fetch an RSS feed on Android API 17.
The library is creating it's own OkHttpClient internally, which does not have tls enabled. The library has no method of setting the OkHttpClient.
Is there a way to set the OkHttpClient instance used by other libraries?

This is the library I am using https://github.com/prof18/RSS-Parser/
and the only way to initialize the Parser object is by using the constructor without any arguments. There also isn't any setter to change the OkHttpclient instance.

Comment: It should be noted that TLS will not be enabled for anything `HTTP`, and you should be using `HTTPS` if you wants to use TLS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is no specific method to set the Client, then you can do 2 things:

1. Ask the developer to add a method like that
2. You can clone the library and add it by your self.

If you want to know how to add tls support ask in comment